# Create a mongoose schema whose value is unique across a value

Tags: mongoose

Consider the database has the following records,

```
{id: 1, device: 'A'},
{id: 1, device: 'B'}
```

Now, If I want to insert `{id: 1, device: 'A'}` the record should not be created as `id: 1` already exists for device `A`.

So, how will the Mongoose schema look?

Answer (score 1):

You can define compound index for this kind of purpose.

Your schema will look like this:

```
const DeviceSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: Number },
    device: { type: String },
})

DeviceSchema.index({ id: 1, device: 1}, { unique: true });
```

For more info please visit [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#Indexes-CompoundKeys)